# regex to trigger anything more than # of characters at end of url

Tags: regex

I have certain urls I need to match to trigger a 410 header in my htaccess while not allowing other urls to trigger the 410.

**URL that need to trigger a 410**

```
http://www.example.com/word-lists/words-that-end-with/letter/farest/
```

**URL that needs to NOT trigger anything**

```
http://www.example.com/word-lists/words-that-end-with/letter/f
OR
http://www.example.com/word-lists/words-that-end-with/letter/f/
```

Basically the urls must only contain 1 letter at the end of the last slash but can or cannot end with a slash. Anything larger than 1 character after that should trigger the regex and 410 the url.

So far this is the regex I have but I think I am over complicating things.

```
RewriteRule 410 /http:\/\/www.example.com\/word-lists\/words-that-end-with\/letter\/[a-z0-9]{2,}/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is nearly correct just two small modification:

1. you need to escape `.` in domain name as well.
2. you can limit query with ^ and $ for beginning and end.

like this:

```
/^http:\/\/www.example.com\/word-lists\/words-that-end-with\/letter\/[a-z0-9]{2,}\/?$/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can greatly simplify your regex; negate the following to get what you want:

`/\/[a-z]\/?$/`

This regex will return true only if the string ends in a slash and a single letter, with a trailing slash being optional.

EDIT:

If you still want to match the entire URL it'd be:

`/^http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/word-lists\/words-that-end-with\/letter\/[a-z]\/?‌​$/`

Comment: I would feel more confortable if I knew it matched `http://www.example.com/word-lists/words-that-end-with/letter/` before it

Comment: You can still add that back in if you'd like.  So it would become `/^http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/word-lists\/words-that-end-with\/letter\/[a-z]\/?$/`.

Comment: this solution works as well but I have potential urls and slashes after that need to be triggered which this would not work. It has to be no more than one character after `letter`

Comment: It doesn't? I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're saying.  The two different regexes I provided wouldn't trigger if there's more than a single letter, that's what the `[a-z]` is controlling.

Comment: There could be a url like `/letter/a/somethingelse/` which would not trigger it. I have to make sure that it triggers after `/letter/a` or `letter/a/` regardless if there is another slash after that.

Comment: I'm sorry, perhaps there is a misunderstanding. You'd have to **negate** the regex I provided.  The regex I provided would ONLY match strings that end in a slash and a single letter and an optional slash after that.  You would negate that match to trigger what you want.  `/letter/a/somethingelse/` would NOT match my regex, which means it would return `true` when negated and trigger your rewrite rule.  Negating it is a bit more efficient than the match you chose, but either solution will technically work.